# How to read an XML file with carriage return &#13; in its contents?

Tags: c#, xml, carriage-return

I need to read an XML file that has 
 chars in some node contents and I need to keep that chars as is and avoid converting them into new lines. Those nodes have xmldsig signatures and converting 
 chars into new lines invalidate the signatures.

I have tried loading the XML with XmlDocument.Load, XmlReader, StreamReader and the special chars ends up converted into new lines.

---

UPDATE with an XML sample

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <description>description&#13;
      with&#13;
      several&#13;
      lines&#13;
      </description>
   </book>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   ...
   </Signature>
</catalog>
```

Comment: Use XmlReaderSettings which has option to preserver white spaces.  The real issue is the writing of the file.  A CRC was done on the file before white spaces were added.  Then used XmlWriter option to IDENT = TRUE which then corrupted the file.  To often people to kludges to fix problems on reading a file instead of going back and fix the problems when the file was created.

Comment: @jdweng the XmlReaderSettings in netcore 3.1 do has a IgnoreWhitespace but defaults to false and I'm setting XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true. Anyway, I need to keep carriage return chars, I have no issues with white spaces right now.

Comment: How was the CRC generated?  Before the XML was written?  Than using IDENT = TRUE added character after the CRC was generated, so you need to remove the returns (not keep them).  Problem is if the file already had returns before doing the CRC you now have some returns that need to kept and other that need to be removed.  How do you know which returns to keep and which to remove?

Comment: We had similar issue at work.  Our solution was to remove returns before Generating CRC.  Our receive end was designed to work with either returns or no returns.

Comment: Not sure why the comments speak of CRC checks whereas the question talks about an XML digital signature. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: I don't know how the XML file was generated, I just receive XML files from different sources and need to process them, I can't remove any character because the digital signature gets invalid. I just know this specific XML has &#13; characters, It seems to me that the XML file was generated with that characters and then signed. When I open the XMl, ej. with XmlDocument.Load, those chars are being replaced with newlines and the signature gets invalid.

Comment: @MichaelKay : A signature is a CRC.

Comment: @jsweng An XML digital signature verifies the integrity of the document and also the authenticity of the person who signed it. A cyclic redundancy check only verifies the integrity. An XML digital signature is XML-aware, a CRC is likely only to look at the binary encoding.

Answer (score 1):

If the CR characters are literal 0x0D bytes, any conformant XML parser is obliged to drop these or convert them to newlines, under the rules for normalizing line endings in the XML recommendation: see https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends.

Generally, any processing of an XML file is going to make changes at the binary level, for example whitespace between attributes will be lost. Your expectation that you can parse and serialize an XML file while preserving its binary representation is fundamentally wrong.

However, the algorithm for XML digital signatures is careful to ignore such variations. It works at a logical level, and should ignore things such as the whitespace within start tags, or the exact representation of line endings. You state that converting CR to NL is invalidating the signature: that sounds wrong to me. The signature should be unaffected.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways to read an XML file with carriage return `&#13;` in its contents:

1. Use an XML parser that supports `&#13;` as a line ending character.
2. Use a text editor that supports `&#13;` as a line ending character.
3. Use a tool that can convert `&#13;` to a different line ending character.

Comment: This doesn't solve issue with reading the corrupted xml file.  It is corrupted because returns were added after a CRC was calculated using XmlWriterSetting IDENT = TRUE.  The real solution is not to use IDENT = TRUE when a CRC was used inside the file.

Comment: This answer misses the point, which is that conformant XML parsers are required to normalize line endings.